# Android Local public class textview creating on constructor

Tags: android, constructor, android-listview, textview

I'm new @andorid development. Pls help me for this.

Here is my question:

I create listview.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:gravity="left|center"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp" 
android:paddingLeft="5dp">

<TextView  android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFF00"
    android:textIsSelectable="true">

</TextView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
    android:textColor="#0099CC"
    android:textIsSelectable="true">

</TextView>
```

And local class declaration:

```
    public class listview_row{
    TextView Text1;
    TextView Text2;
    public listview_row(){
        Text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        Text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    }
}
```

when I create object from this class:

```
        listview_row obListview = new listview_row();
    obListview.Text1.setText(bundle.getString("first_name"));
    obListview.Text2.setText(bundle.getString("last_name"));
```

obListview.Text1 allways equal null and nullobjectexecption is raising. How can I fix this.
I thought I can create textview on constructor, but I was wrong I think.

PS : I want to create Listview with two textview, I used android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 and I can manage to pass data between two acticity with no problem. Now I try to display first_name|last_name @first screen listview.

For more information here is my onActivityResult:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    if ( resultCode == RESULT_OK ){
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 

        if (extras != null){
        switch (requestCode){
        case Activity_New:
            add_new_row( extras );
            break;
        case Activity_Edit:
            edit_row( extras );
            break;
        }}
    }
}
```

and this is add_new_row:
    public void add_new_row( Bundle bundle){
        // Başlık bilgilerini kayıt ediyoruz
        int sayi = HeaderArray.size();
        listview_row obListview = new listview_row();
        obListview.Text1.setText(bundle.getString("first_name"));
        obListview.Text2.setText(bundle.getString("last_name"));

```
    HeaderArray.add(sayi, obListview);
    HeaderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    // Kalem bilgilerini kayıt ediyoruz
    mtable_row obMember = new mtable_row();
    obMember.index = sayi;
    obMember.first_name = bundle.getString("first_name");
    obMember.last_name = bundle.getString("last_name");
    obMember.birth_date = bundle.getString("birth_date");
    itemArray.add(sayi, obMember);
}
```

I use for detail information Array:

```
    private ArrayList<mtable_row> itemArray;

public class mtable_row{
    int index;
    String first_name;
    String last_name;
    String birth_date;
}
```

My main objective is working with two array:
first one is header and second one is item.
header has two field first_name and second_name

and I like to show this array on my main screen.

Comment: What does `Text1` and `Text2` within `listview_row` refer to? You are obviously not setting them....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to create Listview with two textview,

For this i suggest you have a custom listview. Have a custom adapter defined. Inflate a custom layout for each row.

You can pass your values to the constructor of the CustomAdapter.

```
 CustomAdapter cus = new CustomAdapter(this);
 ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
 lv.setAdapter(cus);  

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
Context c;
    LayoutInfator mInflater;
public CustomAdapter(CustomListView customListView) {
    super(customListView, 0);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(customListView);  
    c=customListView;
}
public int getCount() {
    return 20; //listview item count
}

public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

public long getItemId(int arg0) {
return arg0;
}

public View getView(final int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    final ViewHolder vh;
    vh= new ViewHolder();

    if(arg1==null )
     {
        arg1=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customlayout, arg2,false);
        vh.tv1= (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        vh.tv2= (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView2);    
     }
    else
    {
     arg1.setTag(vh);
    }
        vh.tv1.setText("hello");    
        vh.tv2.setText("hello");

    return arg1;
}

 static class ViewHolder
 {
TextView tv1,tv2;
 }
 }
```

Once you pass data between two activities, in the second activity retrieve the data. Each screen has its own UI. You cannot refer to the UI elements like what you have done.

Have two TextViews for your second activity

```
public class SecondActivity  extends Activity{
TextView tv1;
TextView tv2;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.second);
     tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
     tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        tv1.setText(extras.getString("first_name"));
        tv2.setText(extras.getString("last_name"));   
    }

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it this way, you would have to inflate a `Layout` file to pass to your class and use that to get the ids like

```
Text1 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
```

where `layout` is the inflated `layout` you passed in to a constructor. I haven't tried this but something like that would probably work. However, unless you have a need to do it this way it would probably be easier just to keep those `Views` in your `Activitvy`

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

TextViw Text1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);

    Text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    Text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    .....
}
}
```

You are getting a `NPE` because, as far as I can see, you haven't inflated the `layout` file in which these `Views` exist.

Also, a minor thing but you should consider adhering to [Java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) to not get confused or confuse others. Class names should be camel cased and variable names should be mixed case.